# Next/previous window switch in taskbar order in LXDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, lxde, window-switching

I'm using lxde on openbox, lxpanel is opened on the bottom.

I want to achieve to move between tasks/windows fast. But I can't find a way to do that, the feature I want is very simple:

1. An indicator(a small triangle or some other visual indicator) that tells which task/window is currently active
2. when I type Super+n/p to move to the task/window on the right/left.
3. [nice to have feature] provide a way to focus on a task/window by just using keyboard, maybe label the task/window with numbers.

Is there anyway to achieve the above function? or there's some other better recommendation?

Comment: Don’t Alt+Tab and Shift+Alt+Tab do what you want with your Super+N/P?

Comment: @StephenKitt, no. Alt+Tab window lists are not always visible, and the items order are not fixed. The taskbar is easier for navigation from my point of view.